# https://www.getchef.com/chef/install.sh URL no longer exist and throws 503

Tags: dockerfile, nexus, sonatype

I am using the https://github.com/sonatype/docker-nexus3/blob/master/Dockerfile to create nexus docker image and I see that https://www.getchef.com/chef/install.sh URL no longer exist and throws 503.

Can someone please help?

Answer (score 2):

From the [Chef documentation](https://docs.chef.io/chef_install_script/#unix-linux-and-macos):

> On UNIX, Linux, and macOS systems, invoke the Chef Software Install script with:
>
> `curl -L https://omnitruck.chef.io/install.sh | sudo bash`

I assume the previous link has been replaced by the new URL at https://omnitruck.chef.io/install.sh

Comment: Thanks Lucas but I get issue with checksum - ```#7 25.77 [2022-01-26T14:52:17+00:00] FATAL: Chef::Exceptions::ChecksumMismatch: tar_extract[https://download.sonatype.com/nexus/3/nexus-3.37.3-02-unix.tar.gz] (nexus_repository_manager::download line 23) had an error: Chef::Exceptions::ChecksumMismatch: remote_file[nexus-3.37.3-02-unix.tar.gz] (/etc/chef/local-mode-cache/cache/cookbooks/tar/resources/extract.rb line 56) had an error: Chef::Exceptions::ChecksumMismatch: Checksum on resource (1db431) does not match checksum on content (c1db43)```

Comment: Where can I get the checksum for the new version ? NEXUS_DOWNLOAD_SHA256_HASH